# How to use Next-auth to store multiple sessions at the same time

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm working on an integration tool similar to Zappier. I want to use Next-auth to connect to one or more applications and save their access tokens. However, Next-auth only allows for one session at a time. How do I use Next-auth to store multiple sessions at once?

```
export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  secret: 'tsfsdf',
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: 'openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify'
        }
      }
    }),
    {
      clientId: process.env.QUICK_BOOKS_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.QUICK_BOOKS_CLIENT_SECRET,
      id: 'quickbooks',
      name: 'QuickBooks',
      type: 'oauth',
      wellKnown: 'https://developer.api.intuit.com/.well-known/openid_sandbox_configuration',
      authorization: { params: { scope: 'com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting openid profile email phone address' } },
      idToken: true,
      checks: ['pkce', 'state'],
      profile(profile) {
        console.log(profile, 'profile')
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.name,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.picture
        }
      }
    }
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.user.id = token.id
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken
      return session
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id
      }
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token
      }
      return token
    }
  }
}
```